# multiprocessing + subprocess.check_out stuck at exception handling?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm trying to leverage multiprocessing to run a python script with multiple parameter values:

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
def func(n=1):
    output = ''
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output('python script.py -n {}'.format(n), shell=True)
    except:
        pass
    return output

with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as pool:
    pool.map(func, range(100))
```

Somehow Python will stuck but never finishes if one of the values in range(100) causes failure in `func`. I'm fine with those failures returning empty string. Given that the function is taking care of these cases with exception handling (do nothing), why multiprocessing still stuck there? Is there a way to force multiprocessing to skip those failures? Python version Python 3.6.13

Comment: You forgot a `def`. Are you sure that script.py does not enter an infinite loop?

Comment: @azelcer, there's no infinite loop when running script.py but `ValueError: math domain error` for a few values of `n`

Comment: Ah thanks @azelcer! indeed there is a case where infinite loop happened. Closing the ticket now.